# Playing sound when showing popup in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have a frame which pops up whenever an event occurs.

Whenever that frame pops up, I want a sound to be played.

How can I do that in Swing?

Comment: Swings are what kids play on at the park... I think you mean Swing :)

Comment: Note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335601/reliably-playing-a-short-sound-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I play sound in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305/how-can-i-play-sound-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this question in this same site:
[How can I play sound in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305/how-can-i-play-sound-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

A very simple solution is using `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();`

Answer (score 0):

Subclass JDialog or similar and on the constructor/setVisible method of the derived class play a sound with one of the fore mentioned methods.