# Play short (less than 0:00:500 sec) sound clip

Tags: java, android-studio, soundpool

I've faced issue with playing short sound clip with java. Any advice?

```
public static void playAll(String note, String beat, String chord) {

    try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputSoloNote = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(
                "C:/java_support/solo_sound/"+note+"_"+beat+".wav").getAbsoluteFile());
        AudioFormat formatNote = audioInputSoloNote.getFormat();

        AudioInputStream audioInputSoloChord = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(
                "C:/java_support/solo_chord/"+chord+".wav").getAbsoluteFile());

        Clip clipSolo = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clipSolo.open(audioInputSoloNote);
        clipSolo.start();

        Clip clipChord = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clipChord.open(audioInputSoloChord);
        clipChord.start();

        long frames = audioInputSoloNote.getFrameLength();
        double durationInSeconds = ((frames + 0.0) / formatNote.getFrameRate());

        sleep((long) durationInSeconds * 1000);

        clipSolo.stop();
        clipChord.stop();


    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Problem: I am writing an application for my studies about "AI" implementation in the creation of classical music. There is 3 different notes (from duration perspective) - Half (1.2 sec), Quarter (0.6 sec) and Eighth (0.3 sec). This code plays Half and Querter notes in correct manner, however, when it comes to Eighth notes, it just skips them.

I.e:

```
C Quarter C --> play (0.6sec duration) 
F Eighth F --> skip (0.3sec)
E Eighth C --> skip (0.3sec)
F Quarter F --> play (0.6sec)
F Quarter Dm --> play (0.6sec)
C Half F --> play (1.2sec)

... ... ...
```

Solution might me to increase durationInSeconds, however, it will extend all sounds and I don't want to do it.

Also I'd like to find out adaptation to android:
i.e. I want to play 7 short sounds in order.

```
private void playNotes (ArrayList<Data> list) {

    SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        String note = list.get(i).getNote().toLowerCase()+"_eighth";

        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(note, "raw",

    getPackageName());

        int soundId = sp.load(this, resID, 1);
        sp.play(soundId);
        MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resID);

        mPlayer.start();

    }
}
```

what I get is all sound clips are played at the same time. How to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reliably playing a short sound in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335601/reliably-playing-a-short-sound-in-java)

Comment: I've tried all of the answers proposed in that topic, however, either it didn't work at all or it got stuck on first entrie

Comment: You'd either be better to generate the wave form manually for the specified duration or using some form of MIDI which better supports duration

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you expand, please? If I use MIDI, does it mean that it will give me integrated sounds or I will be able to use my own sound database? And can you please send me some documentation about how to manually generate wave? Sorry, if it sounds like a silly question, but I'm a beginner at Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a solution. Don't know if it is broken code, however, for my project works perfectly

```
    try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
```